# What's the name of the "Kit <kitsunde@gmail.com>" form of writing an email address?

Tags: email, naming-conventions

[The RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt) for email addresses defines both that you can use `kit@example.com` as well as `Kit <kitsunde@gmail.com>` but it doesn't appear to be calling them by any special name and so I simply went with "named". Is there a proper name for them?

```
class Email():
    name = "Kit"
    email = "kitsunde@gmail.com"
    named = "Kit <kitsunde@gmail.com>"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems RFC just calls it mailbox.

> Normally, a mailbox is comprised of two parts: (1) an optional
>   display name that indicates the name of the recipient (which could
>   be a person or a system) that could be displayed to the user of a
>   mail application, and (2) an addr-spec address enclosed in angle
>   brackets ("<" and ">").